# Historically, why is there no Node.insertAfter() in the HTML DOM Spec?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

`Node.insertBefore()` has been around since the dawn of time (at least since the [1997 DOM Spec Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-insertBefore)). I'm interested in historically *why* the spec never included an `insertAfter()`. It seems like such low hanging fruit, I have to wonder:

- Were there technical challenges to browser implementation?
- Is there some fundamental limitation to graph traversal with an insertAfter()?
- Was this simply an oversight?

Comment: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2000JanMar/0240.html

Comment: Thanks @Alohci. "Strictly necessary"...interesting choice of criteria considering some of the other convenience features that were included.

Comment: @jpschroeder sounds a bit like nobody bothered to write the specs for it. Or it was some form of [bike-shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) that prevented the spec being ratified.